# Excel converts interval to date

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a simple issue in excel. I want to write this string in a grid: **8-10**

My problem is that excel converts it to the 10th of August of the current year.

How can I turn this conversion mechanic off?

**Edit:** Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter the value as '8-10

The leading ' tells Excel to treat the entry as text.